# How to approximate mysql row count

Tags: mysql

I am trying to see how many rows I have finished in a current batch script. However, when I try and count the rows, it hangs indefinitely (there are about 100 inserts a second occurring on this table). The table is about 3M rows. Here is what I'm doing:

```
select count(*) from my_table where is_done=1
```

The explain also looks pretty good:

```
explain select count(*) from my_table where is_done=1

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  mturk_imdbentry ref is_done is_done 1   const   1471833 Using index
```

Why is this 'lock' occurring, preventing me from retrieving the count? And then secondly, how would I then approximate the count?

Comment: It's probably all the inserts locking the table. The docs suggest you use MyISAM. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/concurrent-inserts.html

Comment: @Phil thanks for this. I think that must be it. Are INSERTs usually faster on MyISAM than InnoDB, or are they relatively equivalent?

Comment: MyISAM is generally better for reading, InnoDB for writing: but if you have only one connection (not a production server), it wont matter much. Just do not forget to wrap your INSERTs in a transaction (for InnoDB)

Answer (score 0):

I once ran into a similar issue on Oracle with extremely large inserts scripts. My workaround was something like this:

```
count = 0;
while(not done) {
   do insert;
   if( count mod 1000 = 0) then
       update count in secondary log table;
   end if;
   count = count + 1;
}
```

If I was doing 100MM inserts I could keep an eye on the pace of the progress and give myself an estimate to completion.